# How to redirect different users to different activities using android studio and a realtime firebase database

Tags: android

I am developing an app on android studio and need to redirect clients and personal trainers to two different activities based on their role. Personal Trainers need to be directed to PTNoticeboardActivity and clients to NoticeboardActivity. Any suggestion on how to do this, here is my login code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    public void loginUser(View View){
        String email = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Log_email)).getText().toString();
        String password = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Log_password)).getText().toString();
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoticeBoardActivity.class));
                    // finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my register activity code below:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  EditText txt_fullname, txt_email, txt_mobilenumber, txt_repassword, 
txt_password;
 Button btn_register;
 RadioButton radioJobClient, radioJobPT;
  DatabaseReference databaseReference;
 FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
 String job ="";
 FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    txt_fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_fullname);
    txt_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_UserEmail);
    txt_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Password);
    txt_repassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_rePassword);
    txt_mobilenumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobilenumber);
    btn_register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_reg);
    radioJobClient = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_Client);
    radioJobPT = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_PersonalTrainer);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");
   // new code

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String  fullname = txt_fullname.getText().toString();
            final String  email = txt_email.getText().toString();
            final String  mobilenumber = txt_mobilenumber.getText().toString();
            final String  password = txt_password.getText().toString();
            final String rePassword = txt_repassword.getText().toString();
            if (radioJobClient.isChecked()){
                 job = "Client";
            }
            if (radioJobPT.isChecked()){
                job = "PT";

            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Please enter Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(fullname)){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Please enter fullname", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                User user = new User(
                                        fullname,
                                        email,
                                        mobilenumber,
                                        password,
                                        job
                                );


                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User")
                                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                        .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));


                                    }
                                });

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }

                            // ...
                        }
                    });




        }
    });


}
public void goLogin (View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
}
```

}

Database structure:
[image: database structure]

Comment: The first step if knowing if the user is a trainer or a client.  How is that data provided?

Comment: I have added my register activity code above

Answer (score 0):

This is the most efficient way to do it:

When your user has created an account, create a child node in the firebase database as role with value as per the user. [could be client or personal trainer]

Then when your activity starts, fetch the value from the database like this:

First of all add a LOGIN BUTTON toyour login activity. When user presses that then only the login thing will take place.

Here is your modified MainActivity.java:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
        String userRole;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btn_login_resource);

            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            String email = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Log_email)).getText().toString();
            String password = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Log_password)).getText().toString();
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            else{          
                firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        jobRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(pAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("job");
        jobRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                try {
                    userRole = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();


                    if(userRole.equals("Client")){
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoticeboardActivity.class);
                    }
                    else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PTNoticeboardActivity.class);
                  }
                }catch (Throwable e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), databaseError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
         }
        }
    }
    });
```

.

Now one thing to care about is that anyone can reverse-engineer this code and illegally can get access to the data. So make sure the data in each activity is hosted in Firebase and you have set the appropriate firebase rules. If you want me to elaborate please let me know in the comments down below.

Comment: Thanks, Would you know how to create a role type child note within the firebase database. databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User"); currently saving both clients and personal trainers under User in the firebase database

Comment: @ConorGormley can you post a screenshot of your database. I might suggest you a better way as per your database

Comment: Have you ever uploaded data to Firebase Database from Android app or should I upload that code too?

Comment: Yes the information is saving to the firebase but the clients and pt are both being saved under the User heading in the database. I will upload a picture when I can

Comment: @ConorGormley did you try my code or do you need more assistance?

Comment: link to my realtime firebase datbase is at the top of the question thanks

Comment: @ConorGormley you added that at top of my answer .... Anyways let me correct and check it right away

Comment: @ConorGormley I see in your Screenshot you have those  user UIDs right? What is parent node of those UIDS???

Comment: @ConorGormley how are you adding those values of phone number, name, email and stuff?? I need that code to. Just respond ASAP and I'll make sure your issue is solved.

Comment: I have added my register page activity above

Comment: @ConorGormley please check my answer once again .. make sure u add that login button as mentioned. And sorry if there are any extraneous `{` such brackets or if they are at wrong place. I've edited this on a phone and I'll correct everything in a while. Until then try this once.

Comment: jobRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(pAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("job"); Getting a error everytime i enter this line